# Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components)...but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The error message is:

> Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined

I am new to react and can't find what is wrong with the code. The error message is telling me to "Check the render method of 'LoginScreen'".

My code:

```
// Import React Navigation
import {
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
} from 'react-navigation';

import tabBarIcon from './utils/tabBarIcon';
// Import the screens
import FeedScreen from './screens/FeedScreen';
import NewPostScreen from './screens/NewPostScreen';
import SelectPhotoScreen from './screens/SelectPhotoScreen';
import React, {Component, Button} from 'react';
/*export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  render(){
    <View>
    </View>
  }
}*/
class LoginScreen extends Component {
  login() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
  }

  render() {
    return <Button title='Login' onPress={() => {this.login()}} />;
  }
}
// Create our main tab navigator for moving between the Feed and Photo screens
const navigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
  {
    // The name `Feed` is used later for accessing screens
    Feed: {
      // Define the component we will use for the Feed screen.
      screen: FeedScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        // Add a cool Material Icon for this screen
        tabBarIcon: tabBarIcon('home'),
      },
    },
    // All the same stuff but for the Photo screen
    Photo: {
      screen: SelectPhotoScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: tabBarIcon('add-circle'),
      },
    },
  },
  {
    // We want to hide the labels and set a nice 2-tone tint system for our tabs
    tabBarOptions: {
      showLabel: false,
      activeTintColor: 'black',
      inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    },
  },
);

// Create the navigator that pushes high-level screens like the `NewPost` screen.
const stackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Main: {
      screen: navigator,
      // Set the title for our app when the tab bar screen is present
      navigationOptions: { title: 'Insta' },
    },
    // This screen will not have a tab bar
    NewPost: NewPostScreen,
  },
  {
    cardStyle: { backgroundColor: 'white' },
  },
);

const TopLevelNav = createStackNavigator({
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Main: { screen: stackNavigator },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
});
// Export it as the root component
export default TopLevelNav;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Button` isn't exported from `react`. Its part of `react-native`. [Source](https://reactnative.dev/docs/button).

Change to:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
```

This error is typically seen when you have an incorrect import. Common reasons include:

- Forgetting to export/import entirely
- Using a mismatched type of import (default/named)
- Importing from the wrong library or path

In this case it was just being imported from the wrong package which will make it `undefined`.